# Making a bracha on the fruit with kedushas shvi'is before another fruit

Tags: blessing, fruits, shmita

In halacha we find that various foods come first in the order of the brachos we make on them. So to for fruit (for example if one is the fruit is from the 7 minim or not.) What about if I would have a fruit (a peach for example) that has on it kedushas shvi'is and a peach that doesn't have keduashs shvi'is (is from outside of Israel.) Is there any reason to make the bracha on the fruit that has kedushas shvi'is before the fruit that doesn't?

Comment: One is a Mitzva to eat one is not a Mitzva to eat. I don't know about Brachot, but you should definitely pick the Shevi'it one first.

Comment: @DoubleAA sounds like an answer, but why?

Comment: I don't think it's an answer as it doesn't discuss Brachot at all. Why should you do a Mitzva before doing a nothing? That seems obvious...